# how to use service stack IoC in controller when MVC run side by side with Service Stack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, servicestack

I create a ASP.NET MVC4 application, run side by side with Service Stack.
The default Ioc container(Funq) works fine with  Servie Stack services which configured in AppHost.

But I'd also use same Ioc framework for my regular ASP.NET MVC4 controllers, it does not work.

I did have this line  in AppHost.Configure(Funq.Container container):
 ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));

But I guess regular ASP.NET does not go though AppHost.

Do I have to do something special with my controller?

And BTW, why FunqControllerFactory class in Validation dll( ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3.dll)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, I resolve it. My bad, I didn't set the property to public. (Ah, the cost to pay to make Ioc work. Ideally I won't set it to public)

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and mark it as such.